# Main Hard Disk Corrupted!

Tags: hard-drive

My main disk (with Ubuntu 16.04 on it) has gotten corrupted.  It drops me into "Busy Box" instead of into the desktop.  I have found (through Google) that I need to put the HD into an enclosure and USB to it, then to do an fdisk on it.

I have done all of that and I can see it, but now I am getting an error as follows:

**Command I am using**
fdisk /media/mike/???/ where ??? is the name of the external hard disk I want to do the fdisk on.

**Error I am getting**
fdisk: cannot open /media/mike/???: is a directory

Thank You,
Mike

Comment: I don't think you had to remove the hdd & put in enclosure; you could have booted a 'live' distro from thumb or dvd & done the same checks from original hardware. As such either you're following strange instructions (maybe you should provide link) or misunderstood them. I'd check hardware (ie. your drive) first (`smartctl`) and I'm not sure what they trying to do with `fdisk` (you didn't display options; -l for list is about all I'd use fdisk for, then `badblocks` maybe, or more likely a `e2fsck` (ext filesystem check; changing if you used a different fs)..

Comment: Please provide more info.  Dropping to `Busy Box` doesn't mean your HD got corrupted completely.  How did you reach `/media/mike/...`? It's the location of mounted disks.  All of the drives located in `/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sdb1,  etc.`

Comment: Use a liveusb or livedvd  then check out your partition with `e2fsck /dev/sd(your partition number)`, the drive must be not mounted`

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall your hard disk back into your computer.

Then to check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: That seems to have worked!  Thank You heynnema!

Comment: @MichaelLaPointe please remember to accept my answer, if it was helpful, by clicking the grey checkmark. Thanks.